# Cython strings support

Tags: python, numpy, cython

I am trying to optimize some code. I have managed to optimize the majority of my project using Numpy and Numba but have some remaining string-handling code that I have not been able to optimize with these tools. Therefore I would like to try to optimize this part using Cython.

The code here takes a run-length encoded string (a letter, optionally followed by a number that indicates how many times the letter is repeated) and expands it. It then converts the expanded string to an array of 0s and 1s using a dictionary lookup to match letters to a sequence of 0s and 1s.

Is it possible to use Cython to optimize this code?

```
import numpy as np
import re

vector_list = ["A22gA5BA35QA17gACA3QA7gA9IAAgEIA3wA3gCAAME@EACRHAQAAQBACIRAADQAIA3wAQEE}rm@QfpT}/Mp-.n?",
                "A64IA13CA5RA13wAABA5EAECA5EA4CEgEAABGCAAgAyAABolBCA3WA4GADkBOA?QQgCIECmth.n?"]


_base64chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz@}]^+-*/?,._"
_bin2base64 = {"{:06b}".format(i): base64char for i, base64char in enumerate(_base64chars)}
_base642bin = {v: k for k, v in _bin2base64.items()}

_n_vector_ranks_only = np.arange(1023,-1,-1)


def _decompress_get(data):
    for match in re.finditer(r"(?P<char>.)((?P<count>\d+))?", data):
        if not match.group("count"): yield match.group("char")
        else: yield match.group("char") * int(match.group("count"))


def _n_apply_weights(vector):
    return np.multiply(vector, _n_vector_ranks_only)

def n_decompress(compressed_vector):
    decompressed_b64 = "".join(_decompress_get(compressed_vector))
    vectorized = "".join(_base642bin[c] for c in decompressed_b64)[:-2]
    as_binary = np.fromiter(vectorized, int)
    return as_binary


def test(x, y):
    if len(x) != 1024:
        x = n_decompress(x)
    vector_a = _n_apply_weights(x)
    if len(y) != 1024:
        y = n_decompress(y)
    vector_b = _n_apply_weights(y)
    maxPQ = np.sum(np.maximum(vector_a, vector_b))
    return np.sum(np.minimum(vector_a, vector_b))/maxPQ

v1 = vector_list[0]
v2= vector_list[1]
print(test(v1, v2))
```

Comment: Relevant code should be included in the question (not off-site).

Comment: Code is 862 chars, too long

Comment: I've edited the code into the question. The main reason for asking this is that we prefer questions to be useful to other people in future, and a link could easily be removed

Comment: Ok, so I remove my comments with code, thanks.

Comment: I've had a go at making the question a bit clearer... check the edit to see if you agree with it.

Comment: Thanks David, now it is more clear. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can get a pretty good speed-up on the second part of the problem (which you're doing through a dictionary lookup) using Numpy alone. I've replaced the dictionary lookup by indexing into a Numpy array.

I generate the Numpy array at the start. One trick is to realise that letters can be converted into the underlying number that represents them using `ord`. For an ASCII string this is always between 0 and 127:

```
_base642bin_array = np.zeros((128,),dtype=np.uint8)
for i in range(len(_base64chars)):
    _base642bin_array[ord(_base64chars[i])] = i
```

I do the conversion into 1s and 0s in the `n_decompress` function, using a built-in numpy function.

```
def n_decompress2(compressed_vector):
    # encode is for Python 3: str -> bytes
    decompressed_b64 = "".join(_decompress_get(compressed_vector)).encode()
    # byte string into the underlying numeric data
    decompressed_b64 = np.fromstring(decompressed_b64,dtype=np.uint8)
    # conversion done by numpy indexing rather than dictionary lookup
    vectorized = _base642bin_array[decompressed_b64]
    # convert to a 2D array of 1s and 0s
    as_binary = np.unpackbits(vectorized[:,np.newaxis],axis=1)
    # remove the two digits you don't care about (always 0) from binary array
    as_binary = as_binary[:,2:]
    # reshape to 1D (and chop off two at the end)
    return as_binary.ravel()[:-2]
```

This gives me a 2.4x speed over your version (note that I haven't changed `_decompress_get` at all, so both timings include your `_decompress_get`) just from using Numpy (no Cython/Numba, and I suspect they won't help too much). I think the main advantage is that indexing into an array with numbers is fast compared to a dictionary lookup.

---

`_decompress_get` probably could be improved using Cython but it's a significantly harder problem...

Comment: I tried the code and with a list of 1000000 vectors as test I passed from 372 secs to 209, very impressive, thanks.
I asked for cython to improve maybe the test part where only numbers are involved, so I wrote something like this:
`cdef np.int_t[:] _n_apply_weights(np.int_t[:] vector):
    return np.multiply(vector, _n_vector_ranks_only)
`

Comment: `cdef np.int_t[:]  n_decompress(compressed_vector):
#    cdef char* decompressed_b64, vectorized
    decompressed_b64 = "".join(_decompress_get(compressed_vector))
    vectorized = "".join(_base642bin[c] for c in decompressed_b64)[:-2]
    cdef np.int_t[:] as_binary = np.fromiter(vectorized, int)
    return as_binary
`

Comment: `cdef double cy_test(x=vector_list[0], y=vector_list[1]):
    cdef np.int_t[:] ix, iy, vector_a, vector_b
    if len(x) != 1024:
        ix = n_decompress(x)
    vector_a = _n_apply_weights(ix)
    if len(y) != 1024:
        iy = n_decompress(y)
    vector_b = _n_apply_weights(iy)
    cdef double maxPQ = np.sum(np.maximum(vector_a, vector_b))
    return np.sum(np.minimum(vector_a, vector_b))/maxPQ
`

Comment: But it doesn't seem to help, it takes more time than numpy.
I'm reading here: https://notes-on-cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/std_dev.html

Comment: This is not the sort of code that Cython is useful for optimizing. All you're doing is calling Numpy functions, which are already written in C, so all you've added is some unnecessary Cython type-checks. Additionally you've turned `n_decompress` into a memory management disaster (your `char*`s are only valid while the variable they point to is alive, but that is a short-lived temporary)

Comment: What you should do next is profile your code (the Python version) to see where the _actual_ problem is. I suspect the slow bit is `_decompress_get` now, but you should measure it. Then work on that.

Comment: ok, the decompress part is the slowest one. So we tried to cythonize only the test part, so in python:
`def test_cython_unp(x=np.load('/tmp/x.npy'), y=np.load('/tmp/y.npy')):
    from ruzicka import trial
    vector_a = _n_apply_weights(x)
    vector_b = _n_apply_weights(y)
    return trial(vector_a, vector_b)

def test_cython_par_unp(x=np.load('/tmp/x.npy'), y=np.load('/tmp/y.npy')):
    from ruzicka import retrial
    vector_a = _n_apply_weights(x)
    vector_b = _n_apply_weights(y)
    return retrial(vector_a, vector_b)`

Comment: `cdef ruzicka(int *a, int *b, int sa):
    cdef int i, max_ab = 0, min_ab = 0
    for i in range(sa):
        if a[i] > b[i]:
            max_ab += a[i]
            min_ab += b[i]
        else:
            max_ab += b[i]
            min_ab += a[i]
    return min_ab * 1.0 / max_ab * 1.0


def trial(a, b):
    return ruzicka( <int *>(np.PyArray_DATA(a.astype(np.int32))), <int *>(np.PyArray_DATA(b.astype(np.int32))), len(a))`

Comment: `cdef float ruzicka2(int[:] a, int[:] b, int sa):
  cdef int i, maxab = 0, minab = 0
  cdef int[::1] max_ab = np.zeros((sa,), dtype=np.int32)
  cdef int[::1] min_ab = np.zeros((sa,), dtype=np.int32)
  with nogil, cython.boundscheck(False), cython.wraparound(False):
    for i in prange(sa, schedule='static', num_threads=16):
      if a[i] > b[i]:
        max_ab[i] = a[i]
        min_ab[i] = b[i]
      else:
        max_ab[i] = b[i]
        min_ab[i] = a[i]
    for i in range(sa):
      maxab += max_ab[i]
      minab += min_ab[i]
  return minab * 1.0 / maxab * 1.0`

Comment: `def retrial(a, b):
    return ruzicka2( a.astype(np.int32), b.astype(np.int32), len(a))`


So ruzicka performing well, but when I try to parallelize (ruzicka2) I'm getting bad performances.